# Is malloc() assigned to another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    int *num;
    num = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

If `malloc()` returns a pointer and `num` is a pointer too, then does that mean that we have two pointers in the end? The returned pointer by `malloc()` simply acts as a "dummy" pointer so that `num` can point to the new memory allocation. Similar to doing `x=y`, where both are pointers.

By "dummy" I mean that you could use `malloc(sizeof(int))` as a pointer if casted to the correct type without needing to define a pointer to assign it to, but that would be too much.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    printf("%d", ((int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int)))[1] = 33);

}
```

---

What I'm trying to says is this. `malloc()` returns an unnamed pointer, so we can't reference it. This means that we need another pointer that is named so that we can reference it and access the memory location. This is done by using `=`. This is similar to doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {   
    int*    x;  
    int*    y;  
    
    x = malloc(sizeof(int));    
    
    *x = 42;      
    
    y = x;      
    
    *y = 13;
    printf("%d", *x)
}
```

To be more specific,

```
y = x;
```

Comment: "*multiple buffers would be opened in File.txt*". What does that mean? `num` is *always* a pointer because that is the type it is defined to be. The return value is not a "dummy" pointer (whatever that means). You are just storing the address returned by `malloc`. It's like a house address. I can give a copy of the address to as many people as I like. It doesn't become a "dummy" house and it is always the same house.

Comment: @kaylum Looks like you copy pasted something from another question.

Comment: @Oka You are right. It's meant to say: "*num is a pointer too.* What does that mean?"

Comment: This question is unclear. In the end we have one pointer. What are you actually asking?

Comment: "*you could use malloc(sizeof(int)) as a pointer*". What do you mean by that? Can you show an example of such a use? But in the end it's still a single address. So it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @kaylum Give me a minute, please.

Comment: @kaylum I provided an example.

Comment: What is the actual question here? Is the value returned by malloc assigned? Yes it is, that's what `=` does.

Answer (score 3):

The key thing to note here is that a *pointer* in C is a variable, but all it "contains" is the memory address where the actual value is located. So `int *num` means "this variable is a memory address whose location contains an 'int' type value". When you first declare it `int *num;` it doesn't point to anything... it's just a junk value. In modern C/C++ you'd really want to initialize it to something, even if it's just zero: `int * num = NULL;`.

> Of the course the variable `num` itself exists in memory somewhere, typically on the local stack or it could be a machine register.

When you call `malloc` that function goes to the operating system and gets *more* memory for your program, and then returns the memory address of that new memory. In the case of `malloc(sizeof(int))` you are telling it to allocate enough bytes to hold an `int` (on a typically PC this is probably 4 bytes).

> In C/C++ the program is now responsible for managing the memory returned by `malloc`, and is expected to call `free` on it eventually.

When your program executes the statement `num = malloc(sizeof(int));`, it's getting a few bytes of new memory allocated to your program, then returning the memory address of the new memory location, and then storing that memory address in the variable `num`. If there was any value there before it's overwritten. In the code above, that's fine because `num` didn't point to anything valid in the first place. That said, you have not actually put anything *into* the new memory location, so that that point you have a valid pointer `num` with the address of a memory location allocated by `malloc` that itself contains some junk integer value.

I have to say that `printf("%d", ((int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int)))[1] = 33);` is an extremely creative line of C code, although it's really terrible code :) This statement does the following:

1. it calls **malloc** which allocates enough space for 3 integers (let's say 12 bytes). The address of the new memory location is then returned by that function.
2. You then "deference" that memory with the `[1]` index operator and set the  *second* integer in that newly allocated 3-int block of memory to the value 33.
3. Because of the way C/C++ works, the value 33 is then passed as an argument to the **printf** function, leaking that allocated 12 bytes which you can't ever get back again because you never kept the memory location returned by `malloc`. Furthermore, the *first* and *third* values in that memory location are uninitialized so they contain junk.

IOW it's the same as `printf("%d", 33);` with a side-effect of leaking 12 bytes of memory, one location of which contains 33 but you have no idea where it's located in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can totally use the return value from malloc directly without assigning it to some variable.

There is just one tiny problem: You have to free the pointer eventually. If you don't assign it to a variable then there is basically only one way to do that:

```
free(malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

and what use would that be?